# How to extract the surface mesh from binary mask of 3D images?

Tags: python, mesh, vtk, itk, geometry-surface

I have a binary mask of 3D medical images in `nii` format which is reconstructed from 2D slices and I need to extract surface mesh from the mask. AFAK, a surface mesh is constructed from the surface points of 3D surface, but I do not have the point sets (vertices).
Do you know any function or software that I can extract the mesh from the binary mask?

Thanks

Comment: vtkMarchingCubes assuming the mask you're talking about is a binary segmentation of the surface you are looking for

Comment: @g.stevo what I mean from the surface mesh is the triangulated mesh like this [link](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Surface_mesher/index.html). Is  `vtkMarchingCubes ` doing the same?